# php curl json post being truncated when sent

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to send a json string in a curl post.  My vendor is telling me the request is being truncated.  I am at a loss.

my code:

```
$url = "https://someServer/json.pl/vendor_account_numbers/list";
    $key = "XXX";
    $secret = "XXX";
    $hash = hash_hmac('SHA1',$url,$secret,$raw_output = false);

$array = array(
    "json" => array(
        "criteria" => array(
            "vendor_id" => array(
                "operator" => "=","data" => "2"
            )
        )
    )
);

    $post = json_encode($array);

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'HMAC:'.$hash,
            'KEY:'.$key,
            'Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($post),
        ));
        echo strlen($post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"json=".$post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    print_r($result);
    $res = json_decode($result);
    exit();
```

The vendor says they are seeing:

```
json:{"criteria":{"vendor_id":{"operator":"=","data":"
```

Comment: With a quick perusal, I don't see anything wrong. Something I do to rule out issues with my code is to maintain a couple simple Apache and IIS endpoints that simply accept whatever I send to them from designated internal addresses that's sent to them via POST or GET, and log it for review. Doing so, I've found issues with one of our vendors who was mishandling XML, and found errors in my output for another vendor, where my JSON was triggering errors on their end.

Comment: Done.  I am seeing the same result as my vendor.  I am sending it to myself locally...

Comment: You are not including the five bytes `json=` in the Content-Length value. Omitting this header should work fine too and remove this whole source of bugs.

Comment: haha read below, just found the issue as submitted this.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the strlen of the post, but in my curl i was adding "json=", thus making the content-length incorrect.

```
    $post = json_encode($array);
    $length = strlen($post)+5;
```

I did 5 because of the json bit in my postfields:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"json=".$post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

`'Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8',`

to this:

`'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Note the semi-colon after the mime type.

If the system doesn't have a content-length requirement (many browsers and some web services do), then set that to zero.